# Cannot resolve import in .proto file

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, goland

I have created following .proto file in the path: microservice/internal/proto-files/domain/repository.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

package domain;

option go_package = "microservice/internal/gRPC/domain";

message Repository {
  int64 id  = 1;
  string name = 2;
  int64 userId = 3;
  bool isPrivate = 4;
}
```

and also following .proto file in another path: microservice/internal/proto-files/service

```
syntax = "proto3";

package service;

option go_package = "microservice/internal/gRPC/service";

import "microservice/internal/proto-files/domain/repository.proto";

//RepositoryService Definition
service RepositoryService {
  rpc add (domain.Repository) returns (AddRepositoryResponse);
}

message AddRepositoryResponse {
  domain.Repository addedRepository = 1;
  Error error = 2;
}
message Error {
  string code = 1;
  string message = 2;
}
```

but my IDE(goland) cannot resolve import in repository-service.proto and also when I use protoc command to generate .pb.go file, I will face following error:

```
microservice/internal/proto-files/domain/repository.proto: File not found.
```

Answer (score 44):

First of all, your import path is better to be like this :

```
import "domain/repository.proto";
```

You must add the path of your proto files to your Goland. for that you must go to `setting` > `Languages & Frameworks` > `Protocol Buffers` then uncheck `Configure automatically`.

After that add this path on import paths.

```
microservice/internal/proto-files
```

like this :
[image]

Comment: unfortunately not fixed by this.

Comment: @Siavoosh also add this line `microservice/internal/gRPC`

Comment: I moved my project to ~GOPATH/src and added ~/GOPATH/src to the configuration path and error has been moved, but still I'm looking for a way to fix it in case I have my project out of GOPATH and using go-mod

Comment: @Siavoosh I updated my answer. I think problem is on your import path.

Comment: even by changing the import path its not resolved. still I'm looking for a way to get rid of this error(cannot resolve '...') while I'm using gomod.

Comment: This works except I selected the root folder that holds all my Proto files. Example, if I have `project/proto/thing/v1/thing.proto`, I would do the above steps but add `project/proto` to the configuration. Then you can import with `import "thing/v1/thing.proto"`. Then reference it in your message like so `this.v1.<message>` where message is item you want to import, eg `Thing`

Comment: This issue should not be closed https://github.com/jvolkman/intellij-protobuf-editor/issues/33

Comment: My compiler warning was gone with this but build is still failing with error, i can click on import to go to the file all that is working but build is failing still with same error, unable to find file on the path

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO The problem is in your proto generator command, please check it

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem; when I use "implort domail/file-name.proto" statements, the IDE gives me the error message:
`Cannot resolve import 'domain/file-name.proto"`

Finally I found my problem: The parent folder was not marked as "Resources Root", so I marked it and that solved my problem.

[image: ide with the problem]